# Generating SQL query to get related results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a theme gallery system. I need to implement a 'related themes' item inside the theme preview page.

Each theme has colors and tags, so between 5 tables i have:

- theme

  - id_theme
  - title
- color

  - id_color
  - title (red)
- tag

  - id_tag
  - title (planets)
- theme_color

  - id_theme
  - id_color
- theme_tag

  - id_theme
  - id_tag

The catch, is that I only have to receive 5 results, and they must show the ones that have more matches between colors and tags. With that requirement, I have no idea on where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: "more matches between colors and tags" What does than mean?

Comment: it means that a '2 tags and 3 colors' match will beat a '0 tags and 4 colors' match, because 2+3 > 0+4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the five themes that have the most items in common with a given theme, you might try something like:

```
DECLARE @target_id_theme INT;
SET @target_id_theme = 1; -- this is the id_theme you want to find similar themes for

SELECT t.id_theme, COUNT(*) as matching_things
FROM theme AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN theme_color AS tc ON tc.id_theme = t.id_theme
LEFT OUTER JOIN theme_tag AS tt ON tt.id_theme = t.id_theme
WHERE tc.id_color IN (SELECT id_color FROM theme_color WHERE id_theme = @target_id_theme)
OR tt.id_tag IN (SELECT id_tag FROM theme_tag WHERE id_theme = @target_id_theme)
GROUP BY t.id_theme
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Not tested, buyer beware, but I hope you get the idea. This creates a row for every color or tag that matches a color or tag assigned to the @target_id_theme, orders them by count descending, and gives you the top 5.

Comment: worked perfectly (with a few minor modifications hehe). thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM theme t
   FULL OUTER JOIN theme_color tc ON tc.id_theme = t.id_theme
   INNER JOIN color c ON c.id_color = tc.id_color
   FULL OUTER JOIN theme_tag tt ON tt.id_theme = t.id_theme
   INNER JOIN tag ta ON ta.id_tag = tt.id_tag
WHERE tag LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%' OR color LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%' OR title LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%'
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the post -- Andrew's solution was more consistent to the problem. The tag/color check had to be summed and filtered by id.